# org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException when starting wildfly

Tags: web-services, deployment, jboss, wildfly-8

I have a project in wildfly 8. On trying to start the server, I get an error as

```
Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."aa.ear".WeldStartService
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] JBAS014613:     
Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "aa.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"aa.ear\".
WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"aa.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type Comparable not present at 
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)_    
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)_  
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)_ at 
sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:108)_   at 
java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:913)_   at 
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverInterfaces(HierarchyDiscovery.java:100)_  at 
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverFromClass(HierarchyDiscovery.java:96)_    
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverTypes(HierarchyDiscovery.java:70)_ at 
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.&lt;init&gt;(HierarchyDiscovery.java:51)_ at 
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.&lt;init&gt;(HierarchyDiscovery.java:44)_ at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:54)_   at 
org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:33)_  
at org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)_sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)_    
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature
Reifier.java:125)_  at 
sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)_    at 
sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:108)_   at 
java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:913)_   at 
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverInterfaces(HierarchyDiscovery.java:100)_  at 
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverFromClass(HierarchyDiscovery.java:96)_    at 
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.discoverTypes(Hierarchy
Discovery.java:70)_ at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.&lt;init&gt;(HierarchyDiscovery.java:51)_  at 
org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.HierarchyDiscovery.&lt;init&gt;(HierarchyDiscovery.java:44)_ at org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:54)_   at 
org.jboss.weld.annotated.enhanced.TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.computeValue(TypeClosureLazyValueHolder.java:33)_  at 
org.jboss.weld.util.LazyValueHolder.get(LazyValueHolder.java:35)_
```

Have done a clean rebuild, clean install of wildfly, restart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I restarted, created a new workspace in Eclipse, checked out the code again, recreated my project , and it worked. No idea why.